# R: fill rows in column by matching rows in another column

Tags: r

This has probably been asked many times, but I only find more complicated cases than mine, and I really don't know where to start. I need to add a new column (`Condition`) to my data frame and fill the rows according to the values in the column `cellNr`

My data frame is `molten.pC`:

```
  cellNr     value
1    G63  0.000000
2    G64  8.848623
3    G65  0.000000
4    G66 10.788718
5    B15  5.285402
6    B16  0.000000
7    B17  0.000000
8    C10  0.000000
9    C11  0.000000
```

I want to add a column `Condition` and fill it like this:

```
  cellNr     value     Condition
1    G63  0.000000  Growth
2    G64  8.848623  Growth
3    G65  0.000000  Growth
4    G66 10.788718  Growth
5    B15  5.285402  Burst
6    B16  0.000000  Burst
7    B17  0.000000  Burst
8    C10  0.000000  Cellularized
9    C11  0.000000  Cellularized
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can do this in `base R` by extracting the first character (`substr`), convert to `factor` with `labels` and `levels` specified.

```
molten.pC$Condition <- as.character(factor(substr(molten.pC$cellNr, 1, 1), 
      levels = c("G", "B", "C"), labels = c("Growth", "Burst", "Cellularized")))
molten.pC$Condition
#[1] "Growth"       "Growth"       "Growth"       "Growth"       "Burst" 
#[6]  "Burst"        "Burst"        "Cellularized" "Cellularized"
```

---

Or we can use `case_when` from `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr) #devel version (soon to be released `0.6.0`)
molten.pC  %>% 
      mutate(Sub = substr(cellNr, 1, 1),
             Condition = case_when(Sub=="G" ~"Growth",
                                   Sub == "B" ~"Burst", 
                           TRUE ~"Cellularized")) %>%
      select(-Sub)
#  cellNr     value    Condition
#1    G63  0.000000       Growth
#2    G64  8.848623       Growth
#3    G65  0.000000       Growth
#4    G66 10.788718       Growth
#5    B15  5.285402        Burst
#6    B16  0.000000        Burst
#7    B17  0.000000        Burst
#8    C10  0.000000 Cellularized
#9    C11  0.000000 Cellularized
```

Comment: to add my thoughts on the solution above:    
molten.pC$Condition <- factor(molten.pC$Condition, levels=sort(unique(str_sub(molten.pC$cellNr,1,1))), labels=sort(c("Growth", "Burst", "Cellularized")))

Comment: Awesome! Thanks!!